# Is Basic Proportionality theorem applicable to trapezium?

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles, ratio, quadrilateral

I was studying vectors and came up with this question

Show that the line joining the midpoints of two non parallel sides of a trapezium is parallel to the parallel sides and is equal to half of their sum.

Is this anyhow mid point theorem for trapezium or is it applicable here?

Comment: If you think that this theorem can be used to prove this fact, I encourage you to try to write that proof in the post! Either you'll answer your own question, or else you'll improve your post by making it more specific and showing your progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just a hint:**
Try the following construction and extend the mid-point theorem for a triangle.

**Additional hint:** Perhaps congruency of triangles somewhere…
[image]